# isearch-yank-word difference between XEmacs and Emacs

Tags: emacs, paste, incremental-search

In XEmacs, if sitting in whitespace, `isearch-yank-word` gobbles the whitespace along with the next word.  In Emacs it does not; it adds one space at a time.  Is there a way to make Emacs `isearch-yank-word` gobble whitespace?

Comment: Using Emacs 24.3.50, Emacs gobbles _all_ the whitespace from point to the next word in one go (C-s C-w), and on a second keypress (C-w) it adds the next word to the search string. So C-s C-w C-w provides the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: You're right; part of my problem is that I'm using 23.1.1.  Even so: with 24.3.2 (latest I could find), it _does_ gobble whitespace, but still does not gobble punctuation.  Is there any way to control it?

Comment: This behaviour is hard-coded, as far as I can see. You could advise the function, but that will take a bit more time to figure out.